# Symbol with FB1&2 , meaning and where can I source it?

Tags: identification, schematics, components

I came across this on a schematic and I'm not 100% sure what its function is.

On the BOM it has a resistor package, denoted like this
FB1, FB2 FB_0 RES 1206 (755-4709) RS CODE (I tried looking this up on RS and got nothing.)

Just from FB I would guess it's a ferrite bead.

[image: unknown symbol]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a surface-mount ferrite bead in 1206 package. Other parameters would include current rating and impedance (usually specified in ohms at 100MHz).

Comment: ah cool, is there anything you can pull from that RS code to help identify what parameters those 2 in particular have.

Comment: They don't seem to have any relationship to the manufacturer's part numbers. You could try calling them for a suggested substitute part. If not, probably a 1K @ 100MHz 1206 part would do, like Murata BLM31KN102SN1L.

Comment: Yeah, going off what ST usually uses i would guess something along the lines of Murata. I've sent them an email asking what specs to go for so we'l see what happens when they come back to me on that. appreciate the follow up mate.

Comment: You can ask RS too. They should have records of what they used to sell.

Comment: I did, they told me that they have deleted the records of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking deeper into google i found a few expired pages off RS that refer to the product 
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/taiyo-yuden/LB3218T1R5M/587-3082-1-ND/2763507